# Making calls on a computer

Tags: windows-xp, networking, dial-up

On my windows xp service pack two, I was wondering if there was a way to make calls using the HyperTerminal with out having to dial up on the network because I already have an active Internet connection through an ethernet cable

Comment: This question makes no sense.  Please define what you mean by "make calls"  (does it have anything to do with a modem ?)  Also, what kind of calls do you want to make (voice, data, fax, and if data, what kind of data)?

Comment: By make calls I mean data and connecting with other computers and yes, it goes straight through the modem but I do not want to dial up and get an Internet connection through that because I already have one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats exactly what terminal emulators (like Hyperterm) do.  If you want to google more information on it (its quite a large topic), search for "Hayes at commands".  Hayes AT commands are the instructions used for communication between virtually all terminals and modems (even the USB cellular modem dongles use them !!)

The basics are (generally - I don't use Hyperterm, and havn't for a long time, and the programs all do pretty much the same thing) to

1. Set the communication parameters for the serial port to speak to the modem.  Typically
   this would be N81   (No parity, 8 bits, 1 stop bit), and a speed at which to talk to
   your modem - 115200 is normally a good choice, but some devices may require a slower
   speed.
2. Initialize the modem.  There are lots of different variants on the string, its been
   10 years since I last did it, but my favourite was "AT&f1&d2&c1".  This may not
   be necessary, and for some modems needs to be changed, but it usually works.  You
   can also try just "at&f1"
3. Use the command "ATDT xxxxxxxx"  to dial out (xxxxxxx being the phone number).  The
   "ATDT" is the Hayes command to issue tones for dialing (as opposed to the older ATDP
   for pulse dialing.
4. From memory, to hang up you send a "+++"  signal down the line.